# Can I check the security policies hit-count in juniper routers via SNMP?

Tags: snmp, juniper

Am trying to see if there is a way to get the output of "show security policies hit-count descending" via SNMP,

it has the following o/p like so,

```
show security policies hit-count descending 
node0:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Logical system: root-logical-system
 Index   From zone        To zone           Name           Policy count
 1       WIFI-DEVICETEST  UNTRUST           allow-internet-traffic-only 284046       
 2       USERS            UNTRUST           allow-all      273438       
 3       AV               UNTRUST           allow-media-to-internet 187757
```

The closest MIB i came to where info related to security policies were is "jnxJsSecPolicyMIB" but Iam unable to figure out how to get the hit count using the MIB.

Comment: Router vendors have their technical support channels. This is not programming related.

Comment: It can be programming related, and is snmp and juniper related; Policy Objects MIB maybe?

Comment: maybe juniPolicyReferenceCount or something at https://mibs.observium.org/mib/Juniper-POLICY-MIB/#juniPolicyReferenceCount; it's a mess--call Support 2x per week for 8 weeks (good luck, the good guys are mostly gone)